# Как сверстать подобный блок без помощи гридов?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет! Кто как думает, как сверстать такой блок? Только не хочется применять гриды, хотелось бы справиться флексами[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в чём? Хочется флексами - верстайте флексами. Всё должно получиться.

Comment: Проблема в том что я не понимаю как это сделать...То есть например та часть на одной строке часы и мужчина в кресле...как это сделать? Вроде как такого контейнера здесь нет, задать каждой из этих колонок по 50% ?А при адаптиве задать блоку flex: wrap?

Comment: именно так. Там явно видно 4 одинаковых блока.

Comment: https://grid.layoutit.com/  удачи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам готовая разметка. Всё делается мгновенно быстро.

```css
.wrapper,
.wrp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.item,
.its {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="wrp">
      <div class="its"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/247/200/300"></div>
      <div class="its"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/257/200/300"></div>
      <div class="its"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/267/200/300"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/277/200/300"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/287/200/300"></div>
  <div class="item">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!!

Comment: на флексах это просто но я ожидал от тебя float но ты сделал на flex хотя требовалось на grid :))